# MVC Entity Framework VB.net error on removerange

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I was given an alredy made project, I don't know if it is code or db first.
My problem is that when I try to remove row from one table or from some other one, it tells me there is a reference with other table and it can't delete them.

I can delete them from the db just fine so there must be something locking them in the code. If someone can give me any tip on where to look it would be helpfull, thank you !

Here is a screen shot of my code:

[image: one line is highlighted]

Here is a screen shot of my database structure:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You should add directly a snip of your code in your post, it is much easier to people to read and understand what's wrong than with an screen shot of your IDE.

Comment: Can we see the error message please?

Comment: I found out that i was using multiple reader at the same time so i added MultipleActiveResultSets=True to my connection now the error is on db.SaveChages and it say Error during the start up of a transacaction with provaider connection(i translated it ).